# How can I retrieve the "Minimum allowed"/"Recommended"/"Currently allocated" values of paging file size on Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows

Windows XP/Vista/7

1. System Properties
2. Advanced tab
3. Settings... button under Performance
4. Advanced tab
5. Change... button
6. The numbers at the bottom of that window in the "Total paging file size for all drives" section

Anybody know how I would go about getting those three numbers from within a C++ program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do some of this using WMI, the class you want is [Win32_PageFileSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394245%28VS.85%29.aspx). In .Net this is (more easily) accessed via System.Management.  If you want runtime usage, you can use [Win32_PageFileUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394246%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Note the elevated privilege you require in that documentation.

I don't see any way to access the minimum and recommended values, at this point.

Comment: @Billy - WMI is still afaik Microsoft's preferred solution for system management. Don't shoot the messenger please. Your alternative looks good but registry modification has its own pitfalls.

Comment: Not shooting the messenger. Just saying :) Getting at WMI data in C++ is just a big freaking cluster f*** :(. +1.

Comment: @Billy - no argument, C# makes this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

That information is stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Session Manager\Memory Managment` in the `PagingFiles` value. It is a `REG_MULTI_SZ`, and each string is of the form:

`PAGINGFILEPATH StartSize MaxSize`

So, for example, I set my C drive to be 16384 MB for both sizes, the key data would look like:

`L"C:\pagefile.sys 16384 16384\0"`

NOTE2: It's possible to omit the numbers, in which case the system manages the size of the page file on the specified drive.

NOTE: The value specified there is not the value the system is **currently** using, but the value that will be used upon system reboot. This is because the paging file generally cannot be changed once the system is running, except to expand the paging file. So if the user would have changed the setting but not rebooted, that key would contain the settings for after reboot, not the settings currently in effect.

If you want the settings currently in effect you can check the sizes of `pagefile.sys` on each of the drives. That won't give you the max size but it will at least give you an idea.

Comment: @Steve: Thank you. +1 to you too :)

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work if Virtual Memory is set to "System managed size".  It only works if you've specified the entries manually.  Otherwise the registry entry just has the filename.
(At least that's true on Vista, not sure about XP/7 at the moment)

Comment: @Drew: "System Managed Size" is just that -- it's not set anywhere, and the Kernel chooses a size it thinks appropriate for the given workload. If there are no sizes, then you can just assume system managed size, and there's nothing more you can say about the pagefile configuration. How the kernel chooses which size to use isn't defined anywhere I can find.